# Unity. Root motion. Полноценное передвижение персонажа

Tags: unity3d

Уважаемые друзья. Делаю игру на Unity. РПГ с управлением как в top-down шутерах. Две недели потратил, пытаясь сделать так, чтобы персонаж бегал и анимировался нормально, управляя им с помощью мыши и WASD. Но потом нашёл для себя Root Motion, который, по сути, должны решить разом все проблемы. Хотел посоветоваться с вами. Как лучше сделать. Вот есть Blend Tree с анимациями ходьбы вперед, назад, влево, вправо. Хочу, чтобы персонаж шел в сторону курсора, когда жмешь W. При этом при нажатии shift, чтобы бежал спринтом. Как лучше делать - спринт в отдельную анимацию с рутмоушеном + boolean триггер isRunning и вызывать при нажатии на шифт? Или можно все в одном древе, а тогда как вызывать? И потом, как лучше прилепить анимации атаки с различных оружием, в новые древа?